# Why is my canvas element showing only a black screen?

Tags: javascript, three.js

I'm setting up a 3d asset viewer in Three.js. I'm running the code on a Plesk server provided by the university and have it linked via Dreamweaver. I'm a total newbie to JS and it was suggested in many threads and posts that I wrap my code within an `'init();'` function. Up doing so, and clearing any errors that the code had, it is now showing a black screen, rather than the 3d model it would show before.

I've spent the whole day error checking removing problems that I was having which included the 'canvas' not being created inside the `'container'` div, and the `'onWindowResize'` function. All these problems have been resolved, and there are no errors in the code apparently. I've got ambient lights in the code and there was a working skybox, so I'm sure its not a problem with position of camera or lack of lighting.

I know that you need as little code as possible, but I have no idea where the problem is coming from, so a majority of the code on the page is here :

```
<div id="container" ></div>
    <script>
    let container;
    let camera;
    let controls;
    let scene;
    let renderer;

    init();
    animate;

    function init(){

    // Renderer - WebGL is primary Renderer for Three.JS
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias : true});
            renderer.setClearColor(0xEEEEEE, 0.5);


    // Selects and applies parameters to the 'Container' div
    var container = document.querySelector("#container");
            container.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
            renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);

    // Perspective Camera (FOV, aspect ratio based on container, near, far)
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, container.clientWidth / container.clientHeight, 0.1, 1000);
        camera.position.x = 750;
    camera.position.y = 500;
    camera.position.z = 1250;

    // Scene will contain all objects in the world
    var scene =  new THREE.Scene();

    //Lighting (Colour, intensity)
    var light1Ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xffffff , 0.3);
            scene.add(light1Ambient);

    var light1Point = new THREE.PointLight(0xfff2c1, 0.5, 0, 2);
            scene.add(light1Point);

    var light2Point = new THREE.PointLight(0xd6e3ff, 0.4, 0, 2);
            scene.add(light2Point);

    // All basic Geomety

    var newPlane = new THREE.PlaneGeometry(250,250,100,100);

        const mesh = new THREE.Mesh(
    new THREE.BoxGeometry(1, 1, 1),
    new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x00ff00} )
                );
        scene.add(mesh);

    // Water
    water = new THREE.Water(newPlane,
            {
                textureWidth: 512,
                textureHeight: 512,
                waterNormals: new THREE.TextureLoader().load( 'http://up826703.ct.port.ac.uk/CTPRO/textures/waternormals.jpg', function ( texture ) {

                texture.wrapS = texture.wrapT = THREE.RepeatWrapping;

                } ),
                alpha: 1.0,
                sunDirection: light1Point.position.clone().normalize(),
                sunColor: 0xffffff,
                waterColor: 0x001e0f,
                distortionScale: 0.5,
                fog: scene.fog !== undefined
                }
            );

            water.rotation.x = - Math.PI / 2;
            scene.add( water );


    // All Materials (Normal for Debugging) (Lambert: color)
    var material = new THREE.MeshLambertMaterial({color: 0xF3FFE2});
    var materialNew = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( {color: 0x00ff00} );



    // Skybox
    var skybox = new THREE.BoxGeometry(1000,1000, 1000);
    var skyboxMaterials =
            [
                new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("http://up826703.ct.port.ac.uk/CTPRO/skybox/blue/bluecloud_ft.jpg"), side: THREE.DoubleSide }),
                new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("http://up826703.ct.port.ac.uk/CTPRO/skybox/blue/bluecloud_bk.jpg"), side: THREE.DoubleSide }),
                new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("http://up826703.ct.port.ac.uk/CTPRO/skybox/blue/bluecloud_up.jpg"), side: THREE.DoubleSide }),
                new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("http://up826703.ct.port.ac.uk/CTPRO/skybox/blue/bluecloud_dn.jpg"), side: THREE.DoubleSide }),
                new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("http://up826703.ct.port.ac.uk/CTPRO/skybox/blue/bluecloud_rt.jpg"), side: THREE.DoubleSide }),
                new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({map: new THREE.TextureLoader().load("http://up826703.ct.port.ac.uk/CTPRO/skybox/blue/bluecloud_lf.jpg"), side: THREE.DoubleSide }),
            ];

    var skyboxMaterial = new THREE.MeshFaceMaterial(skyboxMaterials);
    var skyMesh = new THREE.Mesh (skybox, skyboxMaterial);
    scene.add(skyMesh);

    //Grid Helper Beneath Ship
        scene.add(new THREE.GridHelper(250, 250));



    //OBJ Model Loading
    var objLoader = new THREE.OBJLoader();

    objLoader.load('http://up826703.ct.port.ac.uk/CTPRO/models/ship1.obj', function(object){
            scene.add(object);

    });

    // Object positioning

            water.position.y = -2.5;


    // Misc Positioning

            light1Point.position.z =20;
            light1Point.position.x = 25;


        // z - front-back position
            light2Point.position.z = -400;
        // x - left-right
            light2Point.position.x = -25;
        // y - up- down
            light2Point.position.y = 250;


            window.addEventListener("resize", onWindowResize, false);


        function onWindowResize() {
        camera.aspect = window.innerWidth / window.innerHeight;
        camera.updateProjectionMatrix();

        renderer.setSize(container.clientWidth, container.clientHeight);
    };


    };


    // Canvas adapts size based on changing windows size


    //Render loop

    var animate = function(){

        water.material.uniforms[ "time" ].value += 1.0 / 120.0;
        function drawFrame(ts){
                var center = new THREE.Vector2(0,0);
            window.requestAnimationFrame(drawFrame);
                var vLength = newPlane.geometry.vertices.length;
                for (var i = 0; i < vLength; i++) {
                var v = newPlane.geometry.vertices[i];
                var dist = new THREE.Vector2(v.x, v.y).sub(center);
                var size = 2.0;
                var magnitude = 8;
                v.z = Math.sin(dist.length()/-size + (ts/900)) * magnitude;
            }
    newPlane.geometry.verticesNeedUpdate = true;
    };
        requestAnimationFrame(animate)
        renderer.render(scene, camera);
        controls.update();

    }



    </script>
```

I'm no professional, so I'm sorry if this is super rough for those of you with experience! 
I need to point out, before wrapping all of this in the `init();` function, it was working perfectly.

When working, I should see a crudely modeled ship sitting in some water, with a cloud skybox. The controls were working and it would auto rotate.

Right now it does none of this. The obj loader is working as seen in the chrome console log `OBJLoader: 1661.970703125ms` but again, nothing is actually displayed, it's just a black screen.

Thanks to anyone who's able to help me out with this!

Answer (score 2):

this line

```
animate;
```

needs to a function call

```
animate();
```

Also you probably need to change the code below where you create the animate function from

```
var animate = function(){
```

To this

```
function animate(){
```

The reason is named functions are defined when the code is loaded but variables `var` are created when the code is executed. So with code like this

```
init();
animate();

var animate = function(){ ...
```

`animate` doesn't actually exist at the point the code tries to call it whereas with this

```
init();
animate();

function animate(){ ...
```

it does exist

You could also re-arrange the code so for example define `animate` before you use it should work.

```
var animate = function(){ 
   ...
};

init();
animate();
```

It also appear some are declared inside `init` which means that are not available to `animate`. So for example

```
 var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias : true});
```

declares a new variable `renderer` that only `init` can see. You wanted to set the `renderer` variable that is outside of `init` so change the code to

```
 renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({antialias : true});
```

`controls` is never defined so you probably need to define it or comment out

```
 controls.update();
```

to

```
 // controls.update();
```

note: you might find [these tutorials helpful](https://threejsfundamentals.org) although if you're new to JavaScript you should probably spend time [learning JavaScript](https://eloquentjavascript.net/)

Comment: Hey, thanks for responding so quickly! I have implemented the changes you suggested and now I am seeing this error show up for every frame. Any idea as to why this might be ? ```Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'render' of undefined```

Comment: container and camera don't appear to be referenced in animate but yea, the code is a mess. Hopefully the questioner will take the advice to read some JavaScript tutorials. 

Comment: Thanks for the updates man. After what you mentioned, about removing the word 'var' so that it can be read outside of init, after this a series of issues arose, where'd i'd been doing this throughout the whole document (following a tutorial). Also the orbit controls, I did have something for it which meant 'update();' should work, but i'd accidentally deleted it. But it works now, Thank you so much for the help mate, I really appreciate it!